# How to match words in JavaScript and surround with an expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a plain text like `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` and I want to match some tokens like `Lorem` and `dolor` and replace each of them with a surrounding expression like `<strong>Lorem</strong>` and `<i>dolor</i>`that will contains the matched word i.e. the result of the RegEx match.

So I first wrote down this function to match the same expression:

```
   function replaceTokens(text, tokens, expr) {
      var patterns = [], out;
      tokens.forEach(tuple => {
        var regex = new RegExp("(" + [tuple].join("[.,;:']?\\s*[.!?]?\\s*") + ")");
        var matches = text.match(regex);
        if (matches) {
          patterns.push(regex);
        }
      });
      var regex = combinePatterns.apply(this, patterns);
      out = text.replace(regex, expr);
      return out;
    }
```

where

```
function combinePatterns() {
  return new RegExp('(' + [].slice.call(arguments).map(function (e) {
    var e = e.toString()
    return '(?:' + e.substring(1, e.length - 1) + ')'
  }).join('|') + ')', "gi")
}
```

that will be called like

```
replaceTokens(text,text.split(/\s+/g),"<strong>$1</strong>")
```

This works ok, like here:

```js
function replaceTokens(text, tokens, expr) {
  var patterns = [],
    out;
  tokens.forEach(tuple => {
    var regex = new RegExp("(" + [tuple].join("[.,;:']?\\s*[.!?]?\\s*") + ")");
    var matches = text.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
      patterns.push(regex);
    }
  });
  var regex = combinePatterns.apply(this, patterns);
  out = text.replace(regex, expr);
  return out;
}


function combinePatterns() {
  return new RegExp('(' + [].slice.call(arguments).map(function(e) {
    var e = e.toString()
    return '(?:' + e.substring(1, e.length - 1) + ')'
  }).join('|') + ')', "gi")
}


var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
var rep = replaceTokens(text, ["Lorem", "dolor"], "<strong>$1</strong>")

document.getElementById("in").textContent = text;
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = rep;
```

```html
<div id="in"></div>
<hr>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Now I want to apply different expression for each token, so given the mapping among them I would do like

```
function replaceTokens(text, tokens, expressions) {
  var patterns = [], out;
  tokens.forEach(tuple => {
    var regex = new RegExp("(" + [tuple].join("[.,;:']?\\s*[.!?]?\\s*") + ")");
    var matches = text.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
      patterns.push(regex);
    }
  });
  var regex = combinePatterns.apply(this, patterns);
  tokens.forEach(tuple => {
    out = text.replace(regex, expressions[tuple]);
  });
  return out;
}
```

where `expressions` will be like

```
var expressions = {
  'Lorem': '<strong>$1</strong>',
  'dolor': '<i>$1</i>'
}
```

and it will be called like

```
replaceTokens(text, ["Lorem", "dolor"], expressions)
```

What happens is that I have only the first token replaced, but not the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a function to replace what you need. You'll probably need to set the global flag. I've changed the `expressions` object so it's more programmatically compatible:

```
var expressions = {
  'Lorem': ['<strong>','</strong>'],
  'dolor': ['<i>','</i>']
};

text.replace(regex, function(match, p1) {
  return expressions[token].join(p1) });
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to apply the global flag to your regex, like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(" + [tuple].join("[.,;:']?\\s*[.!?]?\\s*") + ")", "g");
```

Then you should get all matches.

[JavaScript String match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

> "Note: If the regular expression does not include the g modifier (to perform a global search), the match() method will return only the first match in the string".

Comment: If I add the greedy flag in `replaceTokens` function it will not get properly the matching patterns. I have also tried like `out = text.replace(new RegExp("(" +tuple+ ")", 'g'), expressions[tuple]);`, but this will not work as well.